# Packaging multiple weights into one web font

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I'm using Font Squirrel to convert my fonts into useable web versions. I'd like to not have to convert each weight separately and include them in my css (would add alot of bloat with all those calls).

Is there a way to package multiple weights into one font and use the font-weight property to properly call the correct characters?

Trying to avoid the faux-bold and faux-italics here.

Comment: What does faux bold look like? Just curious. Sounds like a good question.

Comment: I haven't converted them yet but it's usually VERY noticeable. It just doesn't look very good.

Comment: @JoshC the faux bold/italic styles are rendered differently by different browsers and OSes (much like webfonts themselves in general) so it varies.  Chrome on Windows often has pretty noticeably terrible faux styles for webfonts, while Safari on an OSX machine usually does a much cleaner job of rendering them.

Comment: @Ennui Interesting. Nice answer btw 1+ to it..

Comment: @JoshC thanks! the "faux bold" thing was a real big annoyance to me back when I first was learning to use webfonts so I dug pretty deep to figure out how to avoid ever having to see that ugly crap again :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the `font-weight` and `font-style` properties accordingly in your `@font-face` calls (instead of FontSquirrel's default output where all of them are set to `normal` and they have separate names for each weight/style instead), and name them all the same font.

Here's an example from a site I built last year:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CartoGothic';
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Book-webfont.eot');
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Book-webfont.svg#CartoGothicStdBook') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CartoGothic';
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Bold-webfont.svg#CartoGothicStdBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CartoGothic';
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-Italic-webfont.svg#CartoGothicStdItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CartoGothic';
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-BoldItalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-BoldItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-BoldItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('library/fonts/CartoGothicStd-BoldItalic-webfont.svg#CartoGothicStdBoldItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Note that FontSquirrel doesn't automatically generate code this way for a reason - which is that some older browsers / user agents do not support `font-weight` and `font-style` properties inside of `@font-face` declarations, so it's more backwards compatible to use the method where you name the fonts differently for each weight and style (CartoGothicRegular, CartoGothicBold, CartoGothicItalic, CartoGothicBoldItalic and so forth).

Also, FontSquirrel actually can do this for you - if you click Expert settings in the Webfont Generator, there is an option under "CSS" called **Style Link** which will output them in this format.

Comment: @DaveRottino make sure you noticed my last edit at the bottom there - Font Squirrel will output CSS in this format if you tell it to under the Expert options when using the webfont generator.  Thanks for marking this the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's to back up Ennui's answer:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Your Font';
    src: url('fonts/SF Your Font.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/SF Your Font.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/SF Your Font.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/SF Your Font.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {    
    font-family: 'Your Font';
    src: url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {    
    font-family: 'Your Font';
    src: url('fonts/SF Your Font Italic.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Italic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Italic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {    
    font-family: 'Your Font';
    src: url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold Italic.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold Italic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/SF Your Font Bold Italic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

There's really no way around the creation of separate fonts, but using the `font-weight` and `font-style` attributes, you will reduce the call. You just declare `font-family` once.

Comment: Exactly!  I updated mine with my own example as well.  Do you happen to know if the declaration order matters (e.g. regular, bold, italic, bold italic)?  I've heard it does but I haven't found any authoritative source for that information.

Comment: @Ennui I heard the same thing for the order as you. I haven't done any testing myself (as in, if it isn't broke :) Oh, and I gave your answer the upvote.