# Select Avenir Next bold variation using CSS (Update 10.10.2)

Tags: html, css, webfonts

Is there a way to specify which bold or italic variations to use in a font like Avenir Next?

Here's an example.  By default a Avenir Next will choose Avenir Next Bold for bold but I would like it to use Avenir Next Demi Bold instead.  [Here is fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pdtk1rjt/)

```
<span style="font-family:'Avenir Next'">
    Normal
    <!-- I want this to be AvenirNext-DemiBold. -->
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Bold</span>
</span>    
<br>
<span style="font-family:'Avenir Next'">Normal</span>
<span style="font-family:'AvenirNext-DemiBold'">Bold</span>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167571/packaging-multiple-weights-into-one-web-font and if you need more information about how to avoid "faux bold", this post covers it well: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles

Answer (score 4):

CSS dosen't let you change font-family for different weights of the same font, unless you start providing your own font files, which is a lot of work for a better looking bold...

However, if you can avoid using inline styles, and instead use the `<strong>` tag to mark bold text, you'll be able to get the exact result you want, and have cleaner HTML:

```css
span {
  font-family:'Avenir Next';
}

strong {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'AvenirNext-DemiBold';
}
```

```html
<span>Normal</span>
<span><strong>Bold</strong></span>   
<br>
<span style="font-family:'Avenir Next'">Normal</span>
<span style="font-family:'AvenirNext-DemiBold'">Bold</span>
```

Comment: with this solution, the drawback is that if someone decides a specific selector that is not a `strong` ought to be bold,  just write `font-weight:bold`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the @font-face rule.

***Update: This seems broken now on OS X 10.10.2.***

```css
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Avenir Next';
   src: local('AvenirNext-DemiBold');
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
 }
```

```html
<span style="font-family:'Avenir Next'">
    Normal
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Bold</span>
</span>
```

Comment: some credits would have been nice, since it's my comment that actually answered your question.

Comment: Not much I can do but upvote your comment since you didn't write an answer.  It's also not completely obvious from the links you posted that it's "src:local(...)" to select a local font which is why I posted this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems broken now on OS X 10.10.2.